# C# Regular expression to match on a character not following pairs of the same charcater

Tags: c#, regex

Objective: Regex Matching

For this example I'm interested in matching a "|" pipe character.
I need to match it if it's alone: "aaa|aaa"
I need to match it (the last pipe) only if it's preceded by pairs of pipe: (2,4,6,8...any even number)

Another way: I want to ignore ALL pipe pairs "||" (right to left)
or I want to select bachelor bars only (the odd man out)

```
string twomatches = "aaaaaaaaa||||**|**aaaaaa||**|**aaaaaa";
string onematch = "aaaaaaaaa||**|**aaaaaaa||aaaaaaaa";

string noMatch = "||";
string noMatch = "||||";
```

I'm trying to select the last "|" only when preceded by an even sequence of "|" pairs or in a string when a single bar exists by itself.
Regardless of the number of "|"

Comment: what do you mean? use `str.LastIndexOf('|')` ?

Comment: Those aren't pairs. I have no idea what this means.

Comment: I need a regex solution, and pairs of characters are to be ignored.

Comment: *I need* is different from *I have tried [something] but failed at [some step]*. If you show what you have tried help could come much faster.

Comment: @bobblebubble how is that right, again?

Comment: There is no right or wrong answer right now as the question is unclear and shows no efforts. It must be closed until OP explains what is wrong with his/her code.

Comment: @bobblebubble when someone asks a poor question it's best to not answer them (even in comments) so that they are forced to rewrite their question, improving the question and the site as a whole.

Comment: @iismathwizard right, thank you! :) I didn't find the question poor, actually interesting but rather unclear at beginning.

Comment: @user937036 the question is a little more clear now, thank you. You still have yet to show us what you have tried, however.

Comment: I was stumped on where to start, sorry for not following protocol

Comment: Bobble Bubble you are the man! Thanks so much, you deciphered PRECISELY what's was needed, Tested & verified.

Comment: @user937036 Try reading up on a basic intro to regular expressions. The regex tag wiki has some links, notably: http://regex.learncodethehardway.org/book/ . You also don't even need to be that close with your attempt for people to be satisfied here. When you show that you've tried something it shows us that you're not running to stackoverflow like a little child when something gets hard; that you're willing to work and try to learn on your own and that you just needed a little help.

Comment: @user937036 thank you! but it was indeed rather unclear when it popped :) going off now, someone will answer and explain if it reopens. Basically my idea is using a [lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to check if `|` is preceded by an even amount of `|` and negative lookarounds as boundaries.

Comment: Look's pretty clear to me. `(?:[^|]|^)(?:\|\|)*(\|)(?:[^|]|$)` Why is this put on **Hold**, any reason ?

Comment: @user937036 Cool how your question developed :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the following regex to select just odd one pipe out:

```
(?<=(?<!\|)(?:\|{2})*)\|(?!\|)
```

See [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3F%3C%3D(%3F%3C!%5C%7C)(%3F%3A%5C%7C%7B2%7D)*)%5C%7C(%3F!%5C%7C)&i=1%7C2%7C%7C3%7C%7C%7C4%7C%7C%7C%7C5%7C%7C%7C%7C%7C6%7C%7C%7C%7C%7C%7C7%7C%7C%7C%7C%7C%7C%7C).

The regex breakdown:

- `(?<=(?<!\|)(?:\|{2})*)` - if a pipe is preceded with an even number of pipes  (`(?:\|{2})*` - 0 or more sequences of exactly 2 pipes) from a position that has no preceding pipe (`(?<!\|)`)
- `\|` - match an odd pipe on the right
- `(?!\|)` - if it is not followed by another pipe.

Please note that this regex uses a variable-width look-behind and is very resource-consuming. I'd rather use a capturing group mechanism here, but it all depends on the actual purpose of matching that odd pipe.

Here is a modified version of the regex for removing the odd one out:

```
var s = "1|2||3|||4||||5|||||6||||||7|||||||";
var data = Regex.Replace(s, @"(?<!\|)(?<even_pipes>(?:\|{2})*)\|(?!\|)", "${even_pipes}");
Console.WriteLine(data);
```

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/QVBSpF). Here, the quantified part is moved from lookbehind to an *even_pipes* named capturing group, so that it could be restored with the backreference in the replaced string. Regexhero.net shows 129,046 iterations per second for the version with a capturing group and 69,206 with the original version with variable-width lookbehind.

**Only use variable-width look-behind if it is absolutely necessary!**

Comment: I've been using this one: (?<=(?<!\|)(?:\|\|)*)\|(?!\|)

Comment: Thanks to you and Bubble Bobble

Comment: Please check my update. If you find my answer helpful, please consider upvoting it.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, it's reopened! If you need better performance, also try this negative improved version.

```
\|(?!\|)(?<!(?:[^|]|^)(?:\|\|)*)
```

The idea here is to first match the last literal `|` at right side of a sequence or single `|` and execute a negated version of the lookbehind just after the match. This should perform considerably better.

- `\|(?!\|)` matches literal `|` IF NOT [followed by](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) another pipe character (right most if sequence).
- `(?<!(?:[^|]|^)(?:\|\|)*)` IF position right after the  matched `|`  IS NOT preceded by `(?:\|\|)*` any amount of literal `||` until a [non](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated)`|` or `^` start.
  In other words: If this position is not preceded by an even amount of pipe characters.

Btw, there is no performance gain in using `\|{2}` over `\|\|` it might be better readable.

[See demo at regexstorm](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5c%7c(%3f!%5c%7c)(%3f%3c!(%3f%3a%5b%5e%7c%5d%7c%5e)(%3f%3a%5c%7c%5c%7c)*)&i=aaaaaaaaa%7c%7c%7c%7c%7caaaaaa%7c%7c%7caaaaaa%0d%0aaaaaaaaaa%7c%7c%7caaaaaaa%7c%7caaaaaaaa%0d%0a%7c%7c%7c%0d%0a%7c%7c%0d%0a%7c%7c%7c%7c)

Comment: I have tested our regexps on regexhero against `a|2||3|||4||||5|||||`: ~78K yours / ~56K mine / ~105K mine for replacing. I came back here as I saw 4 reopen votes. If people believe it a good question, it deserves an answer or two :)

Comment: @stribizhev Thank you for testing! I edited my answer with an improved version of my solution that should even perform a bit better.

Comment: Incidentally I used to play Bubble Bobble extensively, Arcade & console